# When Rachel learned about Chandler and Monica, was this a nod to Sex and the City?

Tags: friends, sex-and-the-city-tv

In *Friends* Season 5, Episode 11, Rachel finds out about Chandler and Monica dating when Rachel overhears them on the phone while Monica calls Chandler "Mister Big".
Mid-season 5 is supposed to have aired somewhere around New Year 1998-1999 ([as its air dates are here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friends_(season_5))) while *Sex and the City* has first aired in 1998 and novel was published in 1997.

Therefore, the timing allows this to be a nod to *Sex and the City*. **So, is it really a reference or just a naughty nickname Monica gave Chandler?**

Comment: "New Year 1998-1999" is an odd construction I've not seen before; does that mean the New Year's Eve/Day when the year 1998 became the year 1999 (i.e. Dec 31st 1998/Jan 1st 1999)?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist yes, exactly. Feel free to edit if you can make that more understandable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While it's technically possible since the first episode of Sex and the City aired in June 1998 while Friends episode 5x11 aired in January 1999, I highly doubt that scene was a nod/reference towards Sex and the City.

Main reason is that Friends has a simple-to-understand story, which is key factor in its success. What you see is what you get, no need to delve deep and search for hidden things, plus unlike cinema movies, the story writers had very short amount of time to finish writing the script for each episode.

So, I put my money that the conversation between Chandler and Monica was just a plain "dirty talk" between two lovers, especially common during initial stages of relationship.

Comment: Although I agree with your general assessment, it's not like Friends didn't have easter eggs. https://www.telltalesonline.com/28264/friends-easter-eggs/